# Isomorphism of $(\Bbb{Z}, *)$ and $(\Bbb{Q}-\{0\}, \cdot)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are there any operations on $\Bbb{Z}$ that makes it isomorphic to $(\Bbb{Q}-\{0\}, \cdot)$ as a group?

Edit: the operation should be made of addition and multiplication of integers, possibly recursively. If there is no such iso, then why?

Comment: Of Course! You could just take some bijection between $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ and artificially *make* it a homomorphism.

Comment: (I apologise for my flippancy - I actually think that this is a nice question. What natural, interesting "multiplications" can we define on the integers, other than just normal addition? And are any of these isomorphic to the non-zero rationals under multiplication?)

Comment: @amWhy You get the group structure for free, because you made sure it was a homomorphism, and because it is a bijection. Bijections are just re-labellings, so that is all that is going on. If I call $3/5$ "7", $2/3$ "12" and $2/5$ "1729" then $7\cdot 12=1729$.

Comment: In its essence, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809800/need-a-binary-operation-on-the-set-of-natural-numbers/). My answer there is in the spirit of the comment made by @user1729 here.

Comment: You have updated to ask about homomorphisms.  There are plenty of homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ with addition to $\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ with multiplication. Given rational $q\neq 0$, define $\varphi_q:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ by $\varphi_q(n)=q^n$.  I don't know if that helps you.

Comment: @JonasMeyer you are right. thanks. I have to edit the post back.

Answer (score 4):

Of course! You could just take some bijection between $\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ and artificially *make* it a homomorphism.

You then get the group structure for free, because you made sure it was a homomorphism and because it is a bijection. Bijections are just re-labellings, so that is all that is going on. If I relabel $3/5$ as "$7$", $2/3$ as "$12$" and $2/5$ as "$1729$" then $7\ast 12=1729$.

Comment: Keywords to live by: "transport of structure".

Answer (score 1):

Cardinality is the only invariant of the underlying set of a group that matters.

If $(G, \circ)$ is a group and you have a bijection of sets $f: G \rightarrow T$, then you can define a group operation $*$ on $T$ so that $f$ is an isomorphism. In fact the operation $*$ is determined by the requirement that $f$ should be an isomorphism.

If $f$ is an isomorphism, then $f(x \circ y) = f(x) * f(y)$. Then

$$x * y = f(f^{-1}(x)) * f(f^{-1}(y)) = f(f^{-1}(x) \circ f^{-1}(y))$$

Of course, you should still check that for any bijection $f$ the operation $*$ above makes $(T, *)$ into a group.

This might seem a bit artificial, but you can see that all group structures $(T, *)$ that are isomorphic to $(G, \circ)$ arise in this manner.

I can see after the edit that this does not really answer your intended question: whether there is a "natural way" (eg using multiplication and addition of integers) to make $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ isomorphic to the multiplicative group of nonzero rationals.